# get package prodNA in R

Tags: r

I just installed R using anaconda, when I am trying to follow this tutorial:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/tutorial-powerful-packages-imputing-missing-values/

specifically this line:

```
iris.mis <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.1)
```

I got the error,

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "prodNA"
```

Does anyone know what might have happened? Thank you.

Comment: You need to load the package first. Maybe library(MICE)

Comment: The tutorial has a section called "List of R Packages". You need to install and then load all of those packages for the rest of the tutorial to work properly in R. `prodNA` is a function in the `missForest` package.